# Remove git pull from master

Tags: git

I was working on production server on `master branch`. Accidently I did

```
git pull origin newbranch.
```

then master is update with new changes . To revert into previous state( I mean to previous commit ) what I have to do.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
$ git reset HEAD~1
```

and eventually with ...

```
$ git add .
$ git stash
$ git stash drop
```

... you can delete all changes.